# Optimizing for timestamp column in Snowflake table

Tags: database-design, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this table with 103.4B rows (approx 1 tb) of data:

```sql
create or replace TABLE SPOT_DIFFDEPTH cluster by (date_trunc('hour', timestamp))(
    TRADE_PAIR VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) NOT NULL,
    ORDERBOOK_SIDE VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    PRICE NUMBER(38,8) NOT NULL,
    QUANTITY NUMBER(38,8),
    primary key (TRADE_PAIR, TIMESTAMP, ORDERBOOK_SIDE, PRICE)
);
```

**Note**: the primary keys were set by the previous data engineer at my workplace. I just recently added the cluster (via `ALTER TABLE SPOT_DIFFDEPTH CLUSTER BY (date_trunc('hour', timestamp));` in an effort to optimize the slow query below)

For pipeline monitoring I would like to frequently (every 3 hours) run a query like this effectively

```sql
      select date_trunc('HOUR', timestamp) as time,
            count(timestamp) as count_
        from SPOT_DIFFDEPTH
        WHERE datediff(hour, timestamp, current_timestamp()) < 5
        group by time;
```

but now it takes slightly more than 1 hour on an X-Small Spark warehouse. The `EXPLAIN` of the above query is:

```
| step | id | parent | operation   | objects        | alias | expressions                                                                                                   | partitionsTotal | partitionsAssigned | bytesAssigned |
|------+----+--------+-------------+----------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+---------------|
|      |    |        | GlobalStats |                |       |                                                                                                               |           63899 |              63899 | 1028495659520 |
|    1 |  0 |        | Result      |                |       | TRUNCTIMESTAMPTOHOUR(SPOT_DIFFDEPTH.TIMESTAMP), COUNT(SPOT_DIFFDEPTH.TIMESTAMP)                               |                 |                    |               |
|    1 |  1 |      0 | Aggregate   |                |       | aggExprs: [COUNT(SPOT_DIFFDEPTH.TIMESTAMP)], groupKeys: [TRUNCTIMESTAMPTOHOUR(SPOT_DIFFDEPTH.TIMESTAMP)]      |                 |                    |               |
|    1 |  2 |      1 | Filter      |                |       | (DATE_DIFFTIMESTAMPINHOURS(TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(SPOT_DIFFDEPTH.TIMESTAMP), '2022-04-06 12:49:54.064000000Z')) < 5 |                 |                    |               |
|    1 |  3 |      2 | TableScan   | SPOT_DIFFDEPTH |       | TIMESTAMP                                                                                                     |           63899 |              63899 | 1028495659520 |
```

Any ideas on improving performance? Is it possible to have a partition of the last 24 hours, so I don't have to query the whole terrabyte of data every time (which BTW is quickly increasing)?

Data is inserted in this table via Task + Stream - maybe I could add a similar task writing to a separate table with only the latest 24 hours data? I'm not sure how I would discard old data from his though.

**Clustering info**
Result of `SELECT SYSTEM$CLUSTERING_INFORMATION('SPOT_DIFFDEPTH');`:

```json
{
  "cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(date_trunc('hour', timestamp))",
  "total_partition_count" : 63867,
  "total_constant_partition_count" : 56576,
  "average_overlaps" : 0.8238,
  "average_depth" : 1.5217,
  "partition_depth_histogram" : {
    "00000" : 0,
    "00001" : 56314,
    "00002" : 509,
    "00003" : 998,
    "00004" : 1343,
    "00005" : 1487,
    "00006" : 1159,
    "00007" : 963,
    "00008" : 483,
    "00009" : 307,
    "00010" : 113,
    "00011" : 53,
    "00012" : 39,
    "00013" : 11,
    "00014" : 0,
    "00015" : 0,
    "00016" : 88
  }
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for this query and also let us know how many records there are in this table

Comment: @NickW sure, updated - number of rows is 103.4B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your SQL WHERE clause needs to reflect your clustering/partitioning in order for Snowflake to be able to prune the partitions effectively e.g.

```
  select date_trunc('HOUR', timestamp) as time,
        count(timestamp) as count_
    from SPOT_DIFFDEPTH
    WHERE date_trunc('hour', timestamp) >= current_date() - 1 DAY -- filter for last 2 days that aligns to the partitions
    AND datediff(hour, timestamp, current_timestamp()) < 5 --refining filter that delivers the subset of data actually required
    group by time;
```

Comment: Thanks, the query time went down to 5 seconds - I'm so happy! I did have to remove `DAY` though from your query, i.e. `WHERE .... >= current_date() - 1`.